# Select forward and backward to arbitrary string in neovim

Tags: vim, ipython, vi, neovim

I am learning to use tmux+neovim+ipython as a scientific python IDE, mostly for data processing and making graphics.

So that I can easily rerun a section of code, how can I make a shortcut that selects forward and backward from the cursor position to some arbitrary marker?. E.g. if the marker is set to `#$%` and my cursor is at the `¶` in the following lines,

```
#$%
x = bigarray[:, 0]
y = bigarray[:, 1]
scalar = 1.5¶
y = y * scalar
axis1.plot(x, y)#$%
```

I would like to enter normal mode, type `<leader>s`, and have this selected:

```
x = somearray[:, 0]
y = somearray[:, 1]
scalar = 1.5
y = y * scalar
axis1.plot(x, y)
```

I found the [object-select](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#object-select) documentation for vim, which is similar to what I want to do, but only works for particular characters.

---

EDIT: It is also important that only the current section is selected if there exist multiple. I.e. with the following file,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#$%
section_1()¶
#$%
stuff_not_in_a_section
#$%
section_2()
#$%
```

`<leader>s` must select only `section_1()`

---

EDIT 2: Using different beginning/ending symbols would be fine as well, e.g. the default foldmarkers of `{{{` and `}}}`.

---

I think combination with [vim-slime](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime/), which sends a selection to ipython, and a matching `set foldmarker`, would make neovim a good IDE. An alternative approach to my situation would also be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that I am mostly happy with. It requires that code sections be defined as marker-based folds/sections, which is approximately how I've been using folds anyways.

If I am within a fold and press `za` to toggle it closed then `C-c C-c` to send a paragraph to vim-slime, the whole fold is sent, regardless of internal linebreaks. The cursor returns to the previous position at the end of the command, as desired.

So in total,

```
nmap <leader>s za<C-c><C-c>za
```

does the trick, albeit with some annoying screen flash as the fold opens and closes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the search pattern:

```
/\v(#\$\%)@<=%(.|\n|\r){-}(#\$\%)@=
```

This will match text between two instances of `#$%`. Then to select the match under the cursor use:

```
nnoremap <leader>s mm/\v(#\$\%)@<=%(.\|\n\|\r){-}(#\$\%)@=<cr>'mgn
```

this will:

1. Mark the cursor position (`mm`)
2. Search for the pattern (`/\v(#\$\%)@<=%(.\|\n\|\r){-}(#\$\%)@=<cr>`)
3. Return to marked position (`'m`)
4. Select matched pattern (`gn`)

Comment: This is certainly going in the right direction! Sadly it does not work for a file containing multiple code sections. I'll update the OP to clarify this requirement.